# regular expression in side [] in python code

Tags: python, regex

Hi I was struggling to get the regular expression in side [] in my code, remaining all working fine this is python script .

this is my code :

```
import re
with open("nfile.cli") as f:
   newlist = f.read()
   cmd = re.search(r'^\W(command=)(".*?")', newlist )
   if(cmd == None):
        print cmd
   else :
        newstr = cmd.group()
        print newstr
        argument = re.search('<.*>', newstr )
        print argument.group()
        option = re.findall("{.*}", newstr )
        print option
        kword = re.search('[.*?]', newstr )
        print kword.group()
```

output:

```
%command="[enable | disable] port <port-no> {force}"
<port-no>
['{force}']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    print kword.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

nfile:
%command="[enable | disable] port <port-no> {force}"%
```

I want to read like: [enable | disable]

thanks

Comment: You don't have to tell your life story in the title.

Comment: Square brackets are used to indicate a class of characters in Python's regular expression syntax (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Side note... use `if cmd is None:` instead of `if cmd == None:`

Answer (score 0):

put \[.*\] for the regex

check the link for validation

http://regex101.com/r/lL9tQ7

JJ